# Vowpal Wabbit multiple class classification predict probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to do multiple classification problem with Vowpal Wabbit.

I have a train file that look like this:

1 |feature_space

2 |feature_space

3 |feature_space

As an output I want to get probabilities of test item belonging to each class, like this:

1: 0.13 2:0.57 3:0.30

think of sklearn classifiers predict_proba methods, for example.

I've tried the following:

1) vw -oaa 3 train.file -f model.file --loss_function logistic --link logistic
vw -p predict.file -t test.file -i model.file -raw_predictions = pred.txt

but the pred.txt file is empty (contains no records, but is created). Predict.file contains only the final class, and no probabilities.

2) vw - csoaa3 train.file -f model.file --link logistic
I've modified the input files accordingly to fit the cs format. csoaa doesn't accept loss_function logistic with following error message: "You are using a label not -1 or 1 with a loss function expecting that!"

If used with default square loss function, and similar output command, I get pred.txt with raw predictions for each class per item, for example:

2.33 1.67 0.55

I believe it's the resulting square distance.

Is there a way to get VW to output class probabilites or somehow convert these distances into probabilities?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do exactly what you want. Before I answer, I would like to know what does "1 |feature_space 2 |feature_space 3 |feature_space" mean. Based on the expected output I think, it is a classification with three classes and label-dependent features. So "2" and "3" are labels, not features? Am I right? Can you provide a real example (may be shortened) of your train.file?

Comment: I'm sorry, my train file actually looks like this: true_class(for ex. 1) |feature_space1 |feature_space2 etc, it just got collapsed in the text for whatever reason. I've edited the original text for more clarity

Comment: Instead of `-raw_predictions = pred.txt` you should use `--raw_predictions=pred.txt` (that is: no space around the equal sign, double dash).

Comment: --raw_predictions=pred.txt is actually used. If you use -raw_predictions = pred.txt you get "option '--data' cannot be specified more than once" error. The command you proposed is what leads to empty raw_prediction file - it is generated, but contains no records

Comment: Can you try this: `cd vowpal_wabbit/test/train-sets/; vw -d multiclass --oaa=10 --raw_predictions=RAW.txt; cat RAW.txt` ? When I try it, RAW.txt is not empty.

Comment: I've tried vw --oaa=3 VW_train.csv --raw_predictions=pred.txt Is it what you intended? Still gives an empty file

Comment: No. What I intended was that you run exactly the command I suggested in  [the given directory cloned from GitHub](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/test/train-sets). If this works then probably there is a problem with your data. If this does not work then there is a problem with your VW installation.

Comment: Ad `VW_train.csv`: Note that VW does not support csv (comma separated values) format, you need to convert it to VW format. I would suggest also to specify the input data explicitly with the `-d` (or `--data`) parameter.

Comment: I've tried what you've proposed. It still outputs an empty file. My vw version is 7.9.0 Could you please tell me your VW version and give an example of output?

Comment: I can confirm, there was a bug in 7.9.0 resulting in the empty raw predictions file. I have version 8.0.2 (the newest from GitHub), but I checked 7.10.0 (and any higher) is OK.

Comment: There is a PR https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/837 which enables much easier way: just add `--probabilities` to the command line. You can try it with `git clone https://github.com/martinpopel/vowpal_wabbit -b probabilities2; cd vowpal_wabbit; make; vowpalwabbit/vw  -d test/train-sets/multiclass --oaa=10 --probabilities -p PROBS.txt; cat PROBS.txt`

Comment: Thank you Martin, I believe this solves the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in VW version 7.9.0 and fixed in 7.10.0 resulting in the empty raw predictions file.

Since [November 2015](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/837), the easiest way how to obtain probabilities is to use `--oaa=N --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`. (Or if you need label-dependent features: `--csoaa_ldf=mc --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`.)