# How get prediction probabilities from Vowpal Wabbit [Python Package]?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, vowpalwabbit

I have read from many resources that you can retrieve prediction probabilities by setting

```
oss_function='logistic'
probabilities=True
oaa=N
```

Ok, I've done this. My script:

```
from vowpalwabbit.sklearn_vw import VW

X = ['1 | feature1:2.5',
     '2 | feature1:0.11 feature2:-0.0741',
     '3 | feature3:2.33 feature4:0.8 feature5:-3.1',
     '1 | feature2:-0.028 feature1:4.43',
     '2 | feature5:1.532 feature6:-3.2']

model = VW(
    convert_to_vw=False, loss_function='logistic', oaa=3, probabilities=True
)

model.fit(X)

print model.predict([' | feature1:0.11 feature2:-0.0741'])
```

This snippet outputs something like:

`[ 28036672.]`

But, I'd like the probabilities for each class, as a softmax layer output:

```
[0.3, 0.6, 0.1]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate?? - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33010248/1168680

Comment: This is about the Python interface, so it is not a duplicate. When using VW directly without Python, `--oaa=3 --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt` works without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, guys. In some of my attempts I could write the probabilities predictions on a file. But it is not an ideal solution, since I'd have to IO the file to retrieve the results.

Comment: @Montenegrodr, I am not even able to write the probabilities to the file; it is empty for me. Will you shre with me how you achieved this?

Comment: @JennaKwon this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/montenegrodr/f69c9637182f3f1bf5356c2b5c9b002e) might help you.